# DNS to ECS containers

Tags: dns, containers, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster in which I run a task with many container. Three of them need to be reached from the internet. These container are exposed on port 80, 8080 and 8880 of the cluster's ec2 instance.
I have a DNS name registered (say example.com), and I can create a CNAME record that points to the ec2 dns name, but if I do so, the app will be reachable as

- example.com:80
- example.com:8080
- example.com:8880

Instead what I would like to do is to reach the three container like this:

- app1.example.com (instead of example.com:80)
- app2.example.com (instead of example.com:8080)
- app3.example.com (instead of example.com:8880)

I can't do it with the DNS CNAME because is not possible with CNAME to redirect to specific ports.

I hope the question make sense.
Any suggestion from anyone would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to place an AWS Application Load Balancer in front of the ECS containers in order to accomplish this. You would have 3 different target groups (one for each container) and configure the Load Balancer to use host-based routing to send the traffic to the appropriate target group/container.